# Añadir claves y valores de un diccionario en un DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Dispongo de un DataFrame vacío, que tiene dos filas con etiquetas.

```
risk_df = pd.DataFrame()
risk_df.index = ['Market Indices', 'Reference Indices']
```

Asimismo también tengo dos diccionarios.

Deseo añadir en ese DataFrame, las key del diccionario cómo etiquetas decolumna y los values, como valores en las columnas. Para ello hago lo siguiente.
Creao una lista de tuplas, donde cada tupla tenga dos elementos: el nombre de la columna y los valores correspondientes de esa columna.
Creo un nuevo DataFrame a partir de la lista de tuplas utilizando el constructor de pandas DataFrame. Asigno el nuevo DataFrame a la variable risk_df y retorno el DataFrame risk_df.devolverla. Lo hago de la siguiente manera.

```
import pandas as pd
# Creamos los diccionarios de indicadores de riesgo
market_risk_indicators = {
    'Annualized Volatility': 1,
    'Sharpe Ratio': 2,
    'Sortino Ratio': 3,
    'Maximum Drawdown': 4,
    'Historical Sharpe Ratio': 5,
    'Historical Drawdown': 6
}

reference_risk_indicators = {
    'Annualized Volatility': 6,
    'Sharpe Ratio': 4,
    'Sortino Ratio': 7,
    'Maximum Drawdown': 9,
    'Historical Sharpe Ratio': 5,
    'Historical Drawdown': 3
}

# Creamos el DataFrame vacío y establecemos las etiquetas de índice
risk_df = pd.DataFrame()
risk_df.index = ['Market Indices', 'Reference Indices']
# Creamos una lista de tuplas con los nombres de las columnas y los valores de cada columna
column_tuples = [(key, [market_risk_indicators[key], reference_risk_indicators[key]]) for key in market_risk_indicators]
# Creamos un nuevo DataFrame a partir de la lista de tuplas
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(column_tuples))
# Asignamos el nuevo DataFrame a la variable 'risk_df'
risk_df = pd.concat([risk_df, new_df], axis=1)
# Imprimimos el DataFrame resultante
risk_df
```

Me devuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual no es lo que deseo. Crea dos filas nuevas y no carga los valores del diccionario en ls otras dos filas. ¿Cuál es mi error?.

Lo intento haciendo.

```
import pandas as pd

# Creamos los diccionarios de indicadores de riesgo
market_risk_indicators = {
    'Annualized Volatility': 1,
    'Sharpe Ratio': 2,
    'Sortino Ratio': 3,
    'Maximum Drawdown': 4,
    'Historical Sharpe Ratio': 5,
    'Historical Drawdown': 6
}

reference_risk_indicators = {
    'Annualized Volatility': 6,
    'Sharpe Ratio': 4,
    'Sortino Ratio': 7,
    'Maximum Drawdown': 9,
    'Historical Sharpe Ratio': 5,
    'Historical Drawdown': 3
}

# Creamos el DataFrame vacío
risk_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Market Indices', 'Reference Indices'])

# Creamos una lista de tuplas con los valores de los indicadores de riesgo
market_risk_values = [(key, market_risk_indicators[key]) for key in market_risk_indicators]
reference_risk_values = [(key, reference_risk_indicators[key]) for key in reference_risk_indicators]

# Agregamos las filas al DataFrame
risk_df.loc[0] = [value for key, value in market_risk_values]
risk_df.loc[1] = [value for key, value in reference_risk_values]

# Agregamos las etiquetas de fila
risk_df.index = ['Market Indices', 'Reference Indices']

# Imprimimos el DataFrame resultante
print(risk_df)
```

y me devuelve el error:

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 30
27 reference_risk_values = [(key, reference_risk_indicators[key]) for key in reference_risk_indicators]
29 # Agregamos las filas al DataFrame
---> 30 risk_df.loc[0] = [value for key, value in market_risk_values]
31 risk_df.loc[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F29X0.png) = [value for key, value in reference_risk_values]
33 # Agregamos las etiquetas de fila

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:818, in _LocationIndexer.**setitem**(self, key, value)
815 self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
817 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 818 iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1785, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
1782     indexer, missing = convert_missing_indexer(indexer)
1784     if missing:
-> 1785         self._setitem_with_indexer_missing(indexer, value)
1786         return
1788 if name == "loc":
1789     # must come after setting of missing

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:2160, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer_missing(self, indexer, value)
2157     if is_list_like_indexer(value):
2158         # must have conforming columns
2159         if len(value) != len(self.obj.columns):
-> 2160             raise ValueError("cannot set a row with mismatched columns")
2162     value = Series(value, index=self.obj.columns, name=indexer)
2164 if not len(self.obj):
2165     # We will ignore the existing dtypes instead of using
2166     #  internals.concat logic

ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Hay otra forma mejor de crear una tabla de resultados?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para futuras preguntas, estaría bien agregar un ejemplo de lo que deseas obtener. *No se si entendí bien,* **¿el resultado que buscas obtener es el siguiente?**

***SOLUCIÓN 1***

```
                   Annualized Volatility  Sharpe Ratio  Sortino Ratio  Maximum Drawdown  Historical Sharpe Ratio  Historical Drawdown
Market Indices                         1             2              3                 4                        5                    6
Reference Indices                      6             4              7                 9                        5                    3
```

De ser así, el código seria:

```
import pandas as pd


market_risk_indicators = {
    'Annualized Volatility': 1,
    'Sharpe Ratio': 2,
    'Sortino Ratio': 3,
    'Maximum Drawdown': 4,
    'Historical Sharpe Ratio': 5,
    'Historical Drawdown': 6
}

reference_risk_indicators = {
    'Annualized Volatility': 6,
    'Sharpe Ratio': 4,
    'Sortino Ratio': 7,
    'Maximum Drawdown': 9,
    'Historical Sharpe Ratio': 5,
    'Historical Drawdown': 3
}

indices=['Market Indices', 'Reference Indices']



# Creamos un DataFrame con los datos de los diccionarios:
#       «market_risk_indicators» y «reference_risk_indicators»
df = pd.DataFrame( data=[ list(market_risk_indicators.values()),
                          list(reference_risk_indicators.values()) ],
                         columns=list(market_risk_indicators.keys()),
                         index=indices )


print(f"\n\n┌─┤ DataFrame ├─┐")
print(df)
'''
┌─┤ DataFrame ├─┐
                   Annualized Volatility  Sharpe Ratio  Sortino Ratio  Maximum Drawdown  Historical Sharpe Ratio  Historical Drawdown
Market Indices                         1             2              3                 4                        5                    6
Reference Indices                      6             4              7                 9                        5                    3
'''
```

***SOLUCIÓN 2***

```
                         Market_risk  Reference_risk
Annualized Volatility              1               6
Sharpe Ratio                       2               4
Sortino Ratio                      3               7
Maximum Drawdown                   4               9
Historical Sharpe Ratio            5               5
Historical Drawdown                6               3
```

Si es así, el código seria este:

```
import pandas as pd


market_risk_indicators = {
    'Annualized Volatility': 1,
    'Sharpe Ratio': 2,
    'Sortino Ratio': 3,
    'Maximum Drawdown': 4,
    'Historical Sharpe Ratio': 5,
    'Historical Drawdown': 6
}

reference_risk_indicators = {
    'Annualized Volatility': 6,
    'Sharpe Ratio': 4,
    'Sortino Ratio': 7,
    'Maximum Drawdown': 9,
    'Historical Sharpe Ratio': 5,
    'Historical Drawdown': 3
}

columnas_nombres=['Market_risk', 'Reference_risk']



# Creamos un DataFrame con los datos del diccionario «market_risk_indicators»
market = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(market_risk_indicators, orient='index')


print(f"\n\n┌─┤ market ├─┐")
print(market)
'''
┌─┤ market ├─┐
                         0
Annualized Volatility    1
Sharpe Ratio             2
Sortino Ratio            3
Maximum Drawdown         4
Historical Sharpe Ratio  5
Historical Drawdown      6
'''



# Creamos un DataFrame con los datos del diccionario «reference_risk_indicators»
reference = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(reference_risk_indicators, orient='index')


print(f"\n\n┌─┤ reference ├─┐")
print(reference)

'''
┌─┤ reference ├─┐
                         0
Annualized Volatility    6
Sharpe Ratio             4
Sortino Ratio            7
Maximum Drawdown         9
Historical Sharpe Ratio  5
Historical Drawdown      3
'''



### Unimos los dos DataFrame «market» y «reference»
#   axis=0 → usa la misma columna, pone primero «market» y debajo «reference»
#   axis=1 → usa una columna diferente, pone primero «market» y a la derecha «reference»
datos = pd.concat([market,reference], axis=1)

# Cambiamos el nombre de las columnas
datos.columns = columnas_nombres



print(f"\n\n┌─┤ datos ├─┐")
print(datos)
'''
┌─┤ datos ├─┐
                         Market_risk  Reference_risk
Annualized Volatility              1               6
Sharpe Ratio                       2               4
Sortino Ratio                      3               7
Maximum Drawdown                   4               9
Historical Sharpe Ratio            5               5
Historical Drawdown                6               3
'''
```

> **XP** *si no es lo que buscabas, déjanos un ejemplo del DataFrame que deseas obtener.*

Comment: Creo que me vale tu propuesta, ya que lo que buscaba, creo que lo podré conseguir transponiendo tu DF reulltante. Yo buscaba una columna con etiqueta 'Ratios' y contenido 'Market Indices' y 'Reference Indices' y el resto columnas con etiqueta 'Annualized Volatility', etc.

Comment: He aplicado la solución 1. Gracias